# How to print a file with spacings in php?

Tags: php

I have a textile that looks like this:

```
Most favourite book: 011 A world apart

4 favourite books: 300, 298, 223, 122
Mad's trial, Go on, Let's Pray, What a life!
```

It is well spaced and neat. 
I am reading this file in php and using echo to print its contents. Echo messes up everything and prints everything in the file in one line. How can I add spaces and make the output look nicer? I am new to php and not very familiar.

```
<div align="center"><h4 style="line-height:150%;"><?php echo $book; ?></h5></div>
```

`$book` here is the file.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to show the text, enclosing it between `<pre>` tags might not be enough. Take a look at php's `nl2br` function, which converts newline characters (`\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Unix or similar) to `<br>` tags. See the function reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php.

In your example:

```
echo nl2br($str);
```

Comment: No, you need to use regex and substitutions if you want to do something special with \t or other whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose your text with `<pre>` tags:

```
$str = "Most favourite book: 011 A world apart

4 favourite books: 300, 298, 223, 122
Mad's trial, Go on, Let's Pray, What a life!";

echo "<pre>". $str . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `echo` function messes up with your text. It is the browser that displays your text without extra spaces. To avoid this you'll have to use `<pre>` html tag. [Tag reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

```
echo '<pre>'. $your_string . '</pre>';
```

Or,

```
<pre> <?php echo $your_string; ?> </pre>
```

Your code must be like this:

```
<div align="center">
    <h4 style="line-height:150%;">
          <pre>
               <?php echo $book; ?>
          </per>
    </h4>
</div>
```